# Is it possible for two instances of the same android app to exist simultaneously?

Tags: android

In a general android app, is it possible for two process instances of the same app to exist simultaneously?

In other words, if I override `Application.onCreate()`, is it possible for `onCreate()` to get called when a previous instance of the app is still running in the underlying linux kernel?

Comment: I don't think so it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given application there will be at most one `Application` instance at any given time.

> When an application component starts and the application does not have any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux process for the application with a single thread of execution. 
>   <sup>[source](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)</sup>

> [The `Application` class is] instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created. <sup>[source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. But it is possible with renaming the application package name inside an apk and recompile it. According to your question its not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Please check activity lifecycle. If you run an activity, it will call oncreate method, if its still in background, then it will call onResume because its in pause state. Linux kernel provides unique identification to each app.

Suppose you run an activity and you called onCreate to run it again, it will call onDestroy or onStop method first, then it will call onCreate.

Comment: The question was about `Application`, not `Activity`.

Comment: yes, I read it. I wrote more about activity so that he can get some idea